# Windows Batch file to delete those lines in a csv file if any of the column is empty

Tags: windows, csv, batch-file

I have a csv file which has 7 Columns:

```
Line 1 : a,b,c,,d,e,f
Line 2 : a,b,c,d,e,f,g
Line 3 : a,b,c,d,e,f,
```

I want to write a batch file in Windows, which when executed would create a new csv 
file containing only non empty rows i.e:

```
Line 2 : a,b,c,d,e,f,g
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "destdir=U:\destdir"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q40489960.txt"
SET "outfile=%destdir%\outfile.txt"
(
FOR /f "usebackqdelims=" %%a IN ("%filename1%") DO (
 FOR /f "tokens=7delims=," %%x IN ("%%a") DO ECHO %%a
)
)>"%outfile%"

GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the settings of `sourcedir` and `destdir` to suit your circumstances.
I used a file named `q40489960.txt` containing your data for my testing.
Produces the file defined as %outfile%

Read each line of the file to `%%a`, then see whether `%%a` has seven tokens. If it does, output it, else skip it.

Comment: Hi @Magoo,
Incase of a space between the commas or the space before first comma, the token count is considered. How to avoid a space being counted?

Comment: Need to know whether any field might **contain** spaces

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method using `find` to find lines with two consecutive commas:

```dos
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "INFILE=sample.csv"
set "OUTFILE=con"

> "%OUTFILE%" (
    for /F "usebackq delims=" %%L in ("%INFILE%") do (
        (echo(",%%L," | > nul find /V ",,") && echo(%%L
    )
)

endlocal
exit /B
```

For this to work, each line needs to be preceded by `,` and followed by another `,` temporarily; otherwise, empty fields at the beginning or at the end of a row would not be recognised.

---

Since CSV data may contain quoted values, which contain literal commas that are not to be considered as separators, the approach becomes more complicated for such files:

```dos
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "INFILE=sample.csv" & rem // (input file; `%~1` is argument)
set "OUTFILE=con"       & rem // (output file; `con` is console)

> "%OUTFILE%" (
    for /F "usebackq delims=" %%L in ("%INFILE%") do (
        set "LINE=%%L" & set "FLAG=#"
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        rem Double " temporarily:
        set "LINE=!LINE:"=""!^"
        for %%I in ("!LINE:,=","!") do (
            endlocal
            if "%%~I"=="" set "FLAG="
            setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        )
        endlocal
        if defined FLAG echo(%%L
    )
)

endlocal
exit /B
```

Answer (score 0):

…and without a for loop?

```dos
findstr/v "\<, ,, ,\>" old.csv>new.csv
```

*This doesn't have a requirement for a set number of columns, just outputs the full ones to the new file*.

Comment: Good idea, but a strings like `a, b, c,d,e,f,g` and `a ,b ,c,d,e,f,g` would not be returned erroneously...

Comment: Strings like that weren't provided; robust solutions require robust questions.

Comment: TBF, a proper csv file would be in the format, `"a","b","c","d","e","f","g"`, and none of us really catered for that!

Comment: Quotation does not change anything for all approaches here so far -- unless a quoted string contains `,` on its own (but such strings were not provided either)...